# Could not access custom view from UIViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am working credit card scanner using custom view. I have tried below code and could not able to access custom class. Could you please anyone help me to fix this issue. Attached error screenshot below. Thanks...

```
let BUTTON_SIZE = CGSize(width: 100, height: 20)
let BUTTON_BUFFER = 10

protocol GymCreditCardScannerViewDelegate: class {
    func creditCardScannerDidCancel(_ scanner: Any?)
    func creditCardScanner(_ scanner: Any?, scannedNumber number: String?)
}

import UIKit

class GymCreditCardScanner: UIView, CardIOViewDelegate {

    weak var scannerdelegate: GymCreditCardScannerViewDelegate?

    var cardIOView: CardIOView?
    var cancelButton: UIButton?
    var doneButton: UIButton?
    var number = ""
    var screenFrame = CGRect.zero
    var innerFrame = CGRect.zero

    func initIntoView(_ superView: UIView?, withDelegate delegate: Any?) -> Any? {

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: superView?.frame.size.width ?? 0.0, height: superView?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0)

        self.scannerdelegate = delegate as? GymCreditCardScannerViewDelegate
        screenFrame = frame
        let MARGIN: CGFloat = 0.05
        innerFrame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width * MARGIN, y: frame.size.height * MARGIN, width: frame.size.width * (1 - 2 * MARGIN), height: frame.size.height * (1 - 2 * MARGIN))
        cardIOView = CardIOView(frame: innerFrame)
        cardIOView?.delegate = self as CardIOViewDelegate
        cardIOView?.hideCardIOLogo = true
        cardIOView?.scannedImageDuration = 0.1
        addSubview(cardIOView!)
        let buttonSize: CGSize = BUTTON_SIZE
        cancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 2 - buttonSize.width / 2, y: innerFrame.origin.y + innerFrame.size.height - buttonSize.height - CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER), width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height))
        cancelButton?.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        cancelButton?.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("handleCancelPress:")), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(cancelButton!)
        superView?.addSubview(self)

        return self
    }

    func remove() {
        if (cardIOView != nil) {
            cardIOView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        cardIOView = nil
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func cardIOView(_ cardIOView: CardIOView!, didScanCard cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!) {

        number = cardInfo.cardNumber
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cardIOView.frame.size, true, 1)
        if let aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            cardIOView.layer.render(in: aContext)
        }
        let capture: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let captureView = UIImageView(image: capture)
        captureView.frame = cardIOView.frame
        addSubview(captureView)
        bringSubview(toFront: cancelButton!)
        cardIOView.removeFromSuperview()
        let frame: CGRect = screenFrame
        let buttonSize: CGSize = BUTTON_SIZE
        doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 2 - buttonSize.width / 2, y: innerFrame.origin.y + innerFrame.size.height - buttonSize.height - CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER), width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height))
        doneButton?.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        doneButton?.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("handleDonePress:")), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(doneButton!)
        doneButton?.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.075, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.doneButton?.alpha = 1
            self.doneButton?.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 2 - buttonSize.width / 2 + (buttonSize.width + CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER)) / 2, y: self.innerFrame.origin.y + self.innerFrame.size.height - buttonSize.height - CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER), width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height)
            self.cancelButton?.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 2 - buttonSize.width / 2 - (buttonSize.width + CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER)) / 2, y: self.innerFrame.origin.y + self.innerFrame.size.height - buttonSize.height - CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER), width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func handleCancelPress(_ sender: Any?) {
        scannerdelegate?.creditCardScannerDidCancel(self)
    }

    func handleDonePress(_ sender: Any?) {
        scannerdelegate?.creditCardScanner(self, scannedNumber: number)
    }
}
```

My ViewContoller

```
class PaymentDetailsVC: UIViewController {

var scanner: GymCreditCardScanner?

//MARK: Credit card scanning
    @IBAction func scanCreditCard(_ sender: Any) {
        cardField.resignFirstResponder()
        scanner = GymCreditCardScanner.initIntoView(view, withDelegate: self)
    }

    func creditCardScannerDidCancel(_ scanner: Any?) {
        scanner.remove()
    }

    func creditCardScanner(_ scanner: Any?, scannedNumber number: String?) {
        scanner.remove()
        scanner = nil
        numberField.text = number
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: your initIntoView must be static class method if you want to call it in that way

Comment: it must be static and also method signature is wrong for your init

Comment: Can you help me on that @NazarLisovyi

Comment: @ReinierMelian check Answer below

Comment: @Siva check my answer and let me know, is not tested but should work

Comment: @ReinierMelian Checking your answer

Comment: @ReinierMelian The method cardIOView and remove facing issue after changing into static. please give me option these two method as well.

Comment: @Siva check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration should be like this

```
static func initInto(_ superView: UIView?, withDelegate delegate: Any?) -> GymCreditCardScanner? {
   //.......

   let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: superView?.frame.size.width ?? 0.0, height: superView?.frame.size.height ?? 0.0)
    let resultCreditCardScanner = GymCreditCardScanner(frame:frame)
    resultCreditCardScanner.scannerdelegate = delegate as? GymCreditCardScannerViewDelegate
    let MARGIN: CGFloat = 0.05
    let innerFrame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width * MARGIN, y: frame.size.height * MARGIN, width: frame.size.width * (1 - 2 * MARGIN), height: frame.size.height * (1 - 2 * MARGIN))
    resultCreditCardScanner.cardIOView = CardIOView(frame: innerFrame)
    resultCreditCardScanner.cardIOView?.delegate = self as CardIOViewDelegate
    resultCreditCardScanner.cardIOView?.hideCardIOLogo = true
    resultCreditCardScanner.cardIOView?.scannedImageDuration = 0.1
    resultCreditCardScanner.addSubview(cardIOView!)
    let buttonSize: CGSize = BUTTON_SIZE
    resultCreditCardScanner.cancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width / 2 - buttonSize.width / 2, y: innerFrame.origin.y + innerFrame.size.height - buttonSize.height - CGFloat(BUTTON_BUFFER), width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height))
    resultCreditCardScanner.cancelButton?.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    resultCreditCardScanner.cancelButton?.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("handleCancelPress:")), for: .touchUpInside)
    resultCreditCardScanner.addSubview(cancelButton!)
    superView?.addSubview(resultCreditCardScanner)
    return resultCreditCardScanner
}
```

then you will be able to do

```
scanner = GymCreditCardScanner.initInto(view, withDelegate: self)
```

Comment: Should be GymCreditCardScanner.initInto instead of GymCreditCardScanner.initIntoView :)

Comment: he just not initialize Scanner

Comment: Could not access CardIOViewDelegate delegate and cardIOView

Comment: @Siva any feedback about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace  `var scanner: GymCreditCardScanner?`  // scanner is nil value you have to initial it

with

```
lazy var scanner: GymCreditCardScanner = GymCreditCardScanner()
```

Comment: yea, but he also wants to set delegate on that

Comment: the issue is he is calling from a class an instance method, in fact he must initialize an object of `GymCreditCardScanner` inside the static function

Comment: he can set delegate later

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using an static function to return an instance of an object in fact is very common and useful way to do this

Answer (score 0):

1. You've written the function `func initInto(_ superView: UIView?, withDelegate delegate: Any?) -> Any? {` but instead you're trying to call the `initIntoView`.
2. function returns the `Any?` instead of `GymCreditCardScanner`. You can cast it like that: 
   `scanner = GymCreditCardScanner.initInto(view, withDelegate: self) as? GymCreditCardScanner` or simply change the function and return the `GymCreditCardScanner?` instead of `Any?`
3. `func initInto`  should be `static func initInto` if you'd like to call it in this way or write your own constructor for this view
4. The `scanner` property is an optional (?), so you should call the `remove()` function like this:
   `scanner?.remove()`